# Prove S = {$s \in \mathbb{R}^k: s \cdot u = s \cdot v = 0$} is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S = \{s \in \mathbb{R}^k: s \cdot u = s \cdot v = 0\}$ ($s, u, v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$). How should I prove that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$?

There's a few steps here: one, I need to verify that the $\vec 0$ exists, and that $ax$, and $x+y$, where $x$ and $y$ are vectors and $a$ is a constant, have the property of $s \cdot u = s \cdot v = 0$.

How should I go about doing that?

Also, if $k=3$, then is there a vector $\vec n$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $S = \operatorname{span} \{\vec n \}$? How so?

Comment: You have outlined what the steps are, where exactly are you running into trouble? Can you verify that $\vec 0$ is an element of $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can show that for any $x,y\in S $ and any $\alpha\in\mathbb R $, that $x+\alpha y\in S $, then $S $ is a subspace.

The answer to your final question would be yes, since $S=\langle u,v\rangle^\perp $ has dimension  $1$.